# What can I do to increase battery life on my Android tablet?

Tags: battery-life, tablet

Tablets have different usage profiles than phones. So many of the "Phone" suggestions don't apply.

So, what can I do to get better battery life on my Android Tablet.
(TechPad 7" Tablet from Chinavasion, S3C6410 Android 1.6;)

Works well, except something unexpected is consuming power; Just having the tabled turned on will drain the battery in 2-3 hours. Also, the power status shows 40% of my battery is always being used by "cell standby";

While this tablet has Wifi, it is disabled. It also has no built-in cell phone, so what could be draining the battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was to delete the Telephony application.  This tables has no phone.  After deleting the following built-in applications, TelephonyProvider & Phone, A new icon appeared in the top box, it was a signal bar strength icon with an X in it.

Now the "Cell standby" no longer appears, and the battery lasts 3-5 hours depending on what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the app PowerTutor, it's a power profiling application that can measure the amount of power that applications and other phone's subsystem takes. Install PowerTutor, let the profiler run, and use the phone/tablet normally for a few days. PowerTutor gives a much more detailed power profile than the built-in Battery Use.

Using PowerTutor, I found that the biggest battery sucker in my Spica is the stock home app, Pantheon; I found a noticeable battery life improvement after replacing Pantheon with Launcher Pro.

The biggest drawback of PowerTutor is that, it is itself a power sucker, it is frequently showing itself as a top power hungry applications.